# How do I decode the timestamp value used by the __utma cookie?

Tags: javascript, datetime

So if i see '1328571956' as the value for the current visit, how do I decode that to a readable value?

thx

Comment: That's seconds after the start of the UNIX epoch (1 Jan 1970, 0:00 UTC).

Comment: So it's literally the native date value of Javascript as explained via http://www.epochconverter.com/programming/. Wanting cred for the answer? & thx much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

don't forget to multiply seconds by 1000 for unix to javascript timestamps:

```
Date.fromUnix=function(n){
    return new Date(n*1000);
}
```

alert(Date.fromUnix(1328571956).toUTCString());

Answer (score 1):

It's a UNIX timestamp. For decoding it into a usable JavaScript date object, there's this: [Convert a Unix timestamp to time in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/847185/convert-a-unix-timestamp-to-time-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

As @wooble above stated... "That's seconds after the start of the UNIX epoch (1 Jan 1970, 0:00 UTC)"

To use it though, do this...

```
var date = new Date(1328571956).toString();
```